# Call Method of JavaScript Not Returning Correct Value

Tags: javascript

```js
const flightName = {
  airline: 'luftansa',
  itaCode: 'LH',
  book: function(flightname, text) {
    console.log(`This is ${flightname},${text}`);
  }
}

flightName.book('indigo', 'johnny');

let book1 = flightName.book;

book1.call('Johnny', 'King');
```

Output:

```
This is indigo,johnny

This is King,undefined
```

Comment: This seems familiar, are you watching course on Udemy by Jonas? :)

Comment: No, it's working perfectly. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: I don't think so, the output should be like

This is indigo,johnny
This is Johnny,King

Comment: The first argument to `call` is *not* the first argument of the called function. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
const flightName ={

airline: 'luftansa',

itaCode: 'LH',

book: function(flightname,text)
{

console.log(`This is ${flightname},${text}`);
}

}

flightName.book('indigo','johnny');

let book1 = flightName.book;

book1.call(this, 'Johnny','King');
```

Answer (score 2):

you are calling your call funciton inccorect, call function is not supposed to work that way, as document [stated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):
you should use it in this manner:

```
call()
call(thisArg)
call(thisArg, arg1)
call(thisArg, arg1, arg2)
```

so you need to change your code to:

```
book1.call(flightName,'johny', 'king');
```